# Excel 2007 - "Cannot complete this task with available resources"

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office-2007, resources, hotfix

The problem can be found in the title. I've been using Office since a very long time. Office 2000, 2003, and now 2007. My office is the Hungarian edition, the SP2 patch have been applied through the Windows Update. So far, I've never seen this problem.

Basically when I try ctrl+a in a file, ctrl+c, and open a new file (ctrl+n), it pop ups this message.

As I said it's been working for a veeeery long time like this. The computer got 3gb free memory, enough CPU, enough everything. Tried applying the SP2 fix again, it didn't work. Found a hotfix for this, `kb956506` but it didn't apply. It said "the expected software cannot be found on your PC".

Now.. I'm stuck. Any idea / suggestion are welcome..

**NEW Information:** It is an Office 2007 Basic OEM. I thought its an in-built limit but it was working for so long .... that just can't be the case. First it works and after someone it doesn't.

Oh yeah I forgot:
- Tried to remove AppData stuff, nothing happened.
- Tried to search for duplicates, but couldn't find anything.
- Total clean install, removing regkeys, settings, blah blah, didn't help.
- I don't have a .xlb file on my PC so deleting it ...is quite impossible.

Here is a video about the problem (Sorry, it is a Hungarian Excel.)
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mYO0Kh4VBrM

---

It turns out, **Ditto** is the problem here. Reported the bug, hope the Ditto devs will fix it since I really love Ditto and it's a must. Once you get used to it, you don't want to abandon it. (Like "Everything";"F.lux" and so on).

Comment: Tried resetting settings. After it finished, the Office set up screen popped up. Typed my key once again, everything is fine, Office up and running. BUT it is still FUBAR. It does not work. Any idea...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently there is more than one reason for this problem.
Here are some references:

[excel cannot complete this task with available resources](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/331985-excel-cannot-complete-this-task-with-available-resources.html)
Two possible actions:

- Delete all files in `C:\Documents and
  Settings\*USERNAME*\Application
  Data\Microsoft\Excel` and reboot
- Search and delete file Excel11.xlb

[Excel 2007: Excel cannot complete this task with available resources](http://www.thecodecage.com/forumz/excel-archives/9806-excel-2007-excel-cannot-complete-task-available-resourc.html)
Save as an .xslx file to solve the problem

[Error message when you open a workbook that contains cells that you filled with a reference to a relative name in Excel 2007: "Excel cannot complete this task with available resources"](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/928976)
Although this doesn't sound suitable according to your description of the problem.

**EDIT**

See this article:
[What to do if you get an out of memory or not enough resources message](http://www.add-ins.com/support/out-of-memory-or-not-enough-resource-problem-with-microsoft-excel.htm)
which contains a lot of advice concerning this problem, too many to list here.

From my side, I would like to ask two questions:

1. What is the memory usage of Excel as seen in Task Manager?
2. What happens if you launch Excel from another user account (create one if required)?

**EDIT2**

Since it works under another user account, I would suggest to:

1. Uninstall Office
2. Verify that everything was really cleaned out as described here:
   [How to manually uninstall the 2007 Office system](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/928218)
3. Run very carefully a few register cleaners, such as [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner), [Eusing Free Registry Cleaner](http://www.eusing.com/free_registry_cleaner/registry_cleaner.htm) or [TweakNow RegCleaner](http://www.tweaknow.com/RegCleaner.php).
4. Reinstall Office.

If this doesn't work, then your user account is really unusable.
Then the best I can think of is to rename it, create a new account that has the same name, and use that instead.

Comment: Tried the Application Data way, and I could only find "Excel12.xlb". Well.. lucky that tomorrow is Saturday so I'll be able to try out all you wrote down (everyone) and hopefully I'll find a solution..just waiting for the install disc.

Comment: @Shiki: Good luck, but I can't guaranty success. Your problem might not be in this list. There is of course also the solution of uninstalling Excel, cleaning out all directories, and reinstalling.

Comment: @Shiki: Excel12.xlb is probably ok to delete instead. But take backups.

Comment: @harrymc - I don't even have a .xlb file on my PC. (Tried Everything tool to search for it). I'll try the ApplicationData stuff now, since reinstall didn't help.

Comment: @harrymc - No, doesn't help. Trying to capture and link a video about what happens maybe someone will come up with the right idea when he sees the video.

Comment: @Shiki: See my edit.

Comment: @Harrymc: Memory: 7980k :D

Comment: @Shiki: The problem is therefore not memory, or probably any other resource. This is a simple Microsoft screw-up. What happens when using another user account (before starting on the long list in my latest article)?

Comment: @Harrymc - It works. F&ck this. My friend told me a workaround. Shoving up a vuvuzela into Balmer's arse... maybe this is the solution I should try. | (ANY IDEAS ARE WELCOME HOW TO CLEAN OUT THE ORIGINAL PROFILE WHERE I WOULD NEED OFFICE).

Comment: @Shiki: See my 2nd edit.

Comment: @Harrymc - Thanks for the long help. I'll try it soon. Ty. (Tried it with shift+right-click>RunAs and select the "exceltest" user where it works, but that pops up the same error.)

Comment: Tried the COMPLETE from ground-up reinstall. No use. Seems like some service or running app interferes. Trying this way.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior can occur if you define names that indirectly refer to other nested names that are more than 20 levels deep. When you add or use a name that exceeds that level of indirection in a formula, you receive this error message. You also receive this error message when you delete a name that is referenced by more than 20 levels of defined names.

Check [KB292471](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/292471/en-us/) for resolution.

Comment: The spreadsheet is really simple. No complex formula, no styling, nothing extra. It is only 300 line long, a few column wide. Just simple, pure, short data. Almost nothing. And it was able to work normally. Something went FUBAR I'm sure. Tried to delete AppData but nothing happens, it won't clear out my settings. Any idea how could I reset everything about Office? I don't really want to reinstall.. (It's an original 2007 Office Professional (or what.. orange color.)

Comment: Did you try Office Repair?

Comment: I'll try. The disc is OEM so I have only a key. I'll ask the person in charge for the disk, hopefully tomorrow I'll be able to install it.

Comment: OK, good luck...

Comment: Reinstalled it, the same thing happens. Any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

If it's related to Ditto then check the size of your Ditto.db.

As I [reported here](https://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3098081&group_id=84084&atid=571690#), the Ditto database grows without limits. Deleting it periodically helps.